# Nesting <i> inside <a> doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I wrote something like this.

```
<li class="settings-selected" role="presentation">
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">English  
        <i class="icon-check right"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

This code working perfectly on other browsers but not in firefox (icon pulled down from the li tag).

[image]

Comment: give a code example reproducing the error, otherwise we can not help

Answer (score 2):

You are using an element which is focused on changing the text contained within and as such the support for it might not be ideal across browsers. I guess you might be doing it for accessibility(?), but that's not a good way to go - the element doesn't contain any text that will get read.

Consider using span for the icon and make sure you give it `display: block;` (or `display: inline-block;`, if you need it inlined) to manipulate with it consistently across the browsers.

EDIT: After reconsidering based on comments, you might try making sure you have the icon aligned to vertical-align: top, as that's a usual Firefox problem (different default setting). If that doesn't work, you are probably having issues with come CSS catching and you'll need to post more code.

Comment: While you are right from a semantics viewpoint, past experience teaches us that other libraries which abuse the `<i>` element work fine across browsers. So that's not the issue here; there must some problematic css that the OP isn't showing us.

Comment: I guess you are right, reconsidered and tested it a bit more and altering my answer.